# Is there a way to set only some query parameters from REST API testobject in Katalon Studio

Tags: katalon-studio, web-api-testing

Suppose my REST endpoint supports 5 different query params, How to setup the testcase so as only the required param alone is sent .

I have created the REST service in Object respository defining all query params. (None of them are mandatory)

I want to write testcases for this with different parameter/value combinations.

Is this possible in katalon studio?

Comment: This is possible, but have you done something we can help you with? Please share what have you tried.